# Proof of correctness of an Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, dynamic-programming, proof-of-correctness

[Edit 1]:- I have no idea why this question was marked as not focused .I am looking for a scientific proof for correctness or incorrectness of this program . If you cant answer/don't have time to answer , I would really appreciate if you can provide references for further reading.

[Edit 2]:- Problem statement :-

> Given a set of positive integer S and an integer K , determine if it
>   can be split into three disjoint subset , each having sum of its
>   element as K and they cover  S.
>
> Example :- S  : {7,3,2,1,5,4,8} and K as 10, Three subsets would be :-
>   { 7 , 3} {5,4,1} {8,2}

Here is the link to the  [3-way-partition](https://www.techiedelight.com/3-partition-problem/) problem. I came up with below solution

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        int[] arr = {7,3,2, 1, 5, 4, 8};
        int sum = 10;
        int[] visited = new int[arr.Length];

        bool v1 = calc(sum, visited, arr);
        bool v2 = calc(sum, visited, arr);
        bool v3 = calc(sum, visited, arr);
        bool v4 = true;

        foreach (var item in visited)
        {
            if (item == 0)
            {
                v4 = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(v1 && v2 && v3 && v4);  
    }

    public static bool calc(int sum, int[] visited, int[] arr)
    {
        if (sum < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (sum == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < visited.Length; i++)
            {
                if (visited[i] == 0)
                {
                    visited[i] = 1;

                    int[] newV = new int[visited.Length];
                    // Array.Copy(visited, 0, newV, 0, visited.Length);
                    if (calc(sum - arr[i], visited, arr) == true)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        visited[i] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My Approach is to solve the problem three times  using backtracking and check if I have any elements left in the array that are un-visited. How can I prove if this algorithm is correct

Comment: Write some unit-tests that contain some sample input, the expected outcome and your actual result. Ideally expected and actual are the same.

Comment: maybe add the code itself, it seems stackoverflow doesn't allow you to insert an iframe

Comment: @HimBromBeere I may be wrong, but I think OP is looking for a "scientific" proof.

Comment: @HimBromBeere:- Passing unit test cases is never a proof that Algorithm is correct

Comment: @Fildor , Yes looking for a scientific proof

Comment: I wish people would explain the reason before down-voting a question.

Comment: Probably your question needs more info regarding the actual problem you are trying to solve, including sample input and desired output. A link to an external site is not considered sufficient substitute of a problem description here. A good question is expected to be self contained.

Comment: The algorithm is incorrect. This is a counter-example: [8 1 1 2 9 9] -- it is  possible to split this array in 3 equal sums -- 8 + 2 = 1 + 9 = 1 + 9. However, the algorithm would pick 8 + 1 + 1 as the first sum, and then it would be unable to produce the two other equal sums -- thus it would erroneously output "False".

Comment: @qwertyman:- Thanks for pointing that out . I will try to work on the same

Comment: You're welcome! A valid solution would be to backtrack directly over all three sets (i.e. to give each element the chance to belong to either set 1, set 2, or set 3 at each step in the backtracking procedure, so that it can backtrack and change the decisions for any element). Otherwise, by choosing a first set somehow independently from the others, and then being forced to stay with that first set (as in the current solution), I think it is hard to guarantee that what remains can still be partitioned in two equal sums

Comment: I have casted a "Reopen" vote. A closed question is reopened at 5 votes. However keep in mind that the probability of getting useful answers for questions of type "How can I do X?" is higher than for questions of type "Prove that my solution for doing X is correct". This site is mainly visited by engineers, not by mathematicians!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proving an algorithm incorrect only requires a counter example:

```
[2,2,1,4,3,3]
```

If the first call takes `[2,2,1]`, then the remaining calls will fail, because `[4,3,3]` can't be split two ways.

If the first call takes `[4,1]`, though, then the other two can get `[2,3]` and `[2,3]`